# AddAttributeToSelect always selects all attributes plus selected attributes

Tags: product, product-attribute

I have added the attributes to select. But it gives all the attributes always. I only need selected atributes to display.

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
//Category id predifined
$categoryId = 132;
$collection = $productModel
             ->getCollection()
             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('device_case_id')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('device_type')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('case_mask_image')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('case_top_image')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('price') 
             ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')                            
             ->setOrder('entity_id', 'asc')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array($categoryId))); 

foreach($collection as $product){
    $data[] = $product->getData(); 
}
```

Comment: select Attribute means

Comment: @AmitBera I need to get only few attributes. Like entity_id,device_case_id etc. But this gives all the attributes of a product plus these selected attributes

Comment: No use getData(), use getter method for getting aata

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the flat products, Magento will always read the attributes that are transformed to columns in the flat table.
To these attributes it adds the ones that are not in the flat table but you specifically tell it to load.
If you have the flat catalog disabled it will only select what you tell it to select and the attributes from the `catalog_product_entity` table (sku, created_at, ...).